# Replacing `dcauchy()` and `dt()` with `rcauchy()` and `rt()` in a Bayesian R code?

Tags: r, random, distribution, bayesian, sampling

Below (in **R code**), I'm showing a simple Bayesian R code in which I use `ddistribution.name()` commands (i.e., `dcauchy()`, `dt()`) to estimate what I call "`x`" in my code. I then plot the answers.

**Coding Question:**

I was wondering if I could achieve an approximately similar answer using `rdistribution.name()` commands (e.g., `rcauchy()`, `rt()`) to estimate what I call "`x`" in my code?

(**P.S.:** Using `rdistribution.name()` commands, I should then be able to *histogram* the answers.)

```
     prior = function(x) dcauchy(x)
likelihood = function(x) dt(1.46, 19, x*sqrt(20))
 posterior = function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)  

 plot(x <- seq(-5, 5, len = 1e4), posterior(x), col = 3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but simply replacing `d_()` by `r_()` doesn't seem like it would make much sense. You can of course create simulations which illustrate Bayes' theorem, but I don't see how such simulations would be obtained by simply replacing `d_()` by `r_()` in a formula for a posterior distribution.

Comment: @JohnColeman, right that's what I'm trying to understand how the integral approach above could be turned into a corresponding simulation approach?

Comment: The `Metropolis Algorithm` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) is a good way to generate numbers which follow a posterior distribution. The book "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" by John Krushke has a nice introduction to it. The core algorithm is easy enough to code directly in R, though I am sure that various packages already implement it. This might be overkill for a 1-dimensional case, but is nevertheless a natural way to proceed. The nice thing about the algorithm is that you don't need the denominator in Bayes' theorem,`prior*lilelihood` suffices.